# CSS-only styling for a checkbox `input` as a flip switch, and keep its existing `label`

Tags: html, css

How can I (CSS-only) style an `input` with `type="checkbox"`, and keep the existing `label` declared `for` that input element?

```html
<p id="lorem-ipsum">
    <label for="dolor-sit-amet">Dolor sit amet</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="dolor-sit-amet" name="dolor" />
</p>
```

I want to style the checkbox element so that it has a "flip switch" appearance and behaviour.

### Keep the existing `label`

There are numerous articles (an [example from 2012](https://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/)) that describe this kind of complete change to the appearance of a checkbox, but I haven't found one that lets the label (as already used in the above document) remain untouched.

For this reason, many of the answers in [this similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css) do not apply here.

In other words: I want to keep the `label` element as already written, *and* I want to have the checkbox styled like a flip switch with "on" and "off" inside it.

How can I do that *without* changing or styling the existing `label` element, and instead styling the `input` element?

Comment: "How can I do that without changing the existing label element, by styling just the input element?" - by just styling the `input`, you're still out of luck. The answer by [Aje](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52713990/4665) is a great compromise by using `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements.

Comment: @JonP, thanks for helping me clarify. I am updating the question to be clear it's specifically the `label` I want to avoid changing.

Answer (score 2):

if you can change the sequence in `label` and `input`, here is an idea.
you can change the colors and add animation as per your requirement.

```css
label{
position:relative;
display:block;
width:200px;
}
label:before{
  content:'off';
  width:50px;
  height:20px;
  background:#eee;
  border-radius:50px;
  position:absolute;
  right:0
  
}
label:after{
  content:'';
  width:18px;
  height:18px;
  background:#333;
  border-radius:50px;
  position:absolute;
  right:1px;
  top:1px;
  
}
input:checked + label:before{
  content:'on';
  text-indent: 25px;
  
  
}
input:checked + label:after{
  right:29px;
  top:1px;
  
}
```

```html
<p id="lorem-ipsum">
    <input type="checkbox" id="dolor-sit-amet" name="dolor" />
    <label for="dolor-sit-amet">Dolor sit amet</label>
    
</p>
```

Comment: This is intriguing, but doesn't hit the mark. I do still want to have the switch appear in the same position (before the label). Also, tying the extra content so closely to the label element forecloses other styling of the label. I've used this to build [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52720932/70157), though, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The `:before` and `:after` selectors can create some of the content. By adding another element (for example, a `span`) that can be styled to appear as the “slider” of the switch.

Then, the containing element – which can be the `label` itself! – can also have `:before` and `:after` selectors used to style the “socket” in which the slider moves.

```css
input[type=checkbox].switch {
    display: none;
}

label.switch.socket {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    text-indent: 6.0ex;
}
span.switch.slider {
    display: inline-block;
}
label.switch.socket span.switch.slider:before {
    content: "off";
    text-indent: 2.3ex;
    width: 5.5ex;
    height: 2.2ex;
    color: White;
    background: DimGray;
    border-radius: 5.5ex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
label.switch span.switch.slider:after {
    content: "";
    width: 2.0ex;
    height: 2.0ex;
    background: Gainsboro;
    border-radius: 5.5ex;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0.1ex;
    top: 0.1ex;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
label.switch.socket input[type=checkbox]:checked + span.slider:before {
    content: "on";
    text-indent: 0.5ex;
    color: Black;
    background: DarkGray;
}
label.switch.socket input[type=checkbox]:checked + span.slider:after {
    left: 3.4ex;
}
```

```html
<p>
    <label class="switch socket">
        <input type="checkbox" class="switch" name="lorem" />
        <span class="switch slider" />
        Lorem ipsum
    </label>

    <label class="switch socket">
        <input type="checkbox" class="switch" name="dolor" checked />
        <span class="switch slider round" />
        Dolor sit amet
    </label>
</p>
```

(Thanks to @gosi123 and @aje for suggestions that came close enough to help me formulate this answer.)