# What is the name of this switch like user interface control?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to make something similar to this control :

[image]

What is it? does it have any events?

Comment: It's a switch. They are usually implemented using an input element of `type="checkbox"` but can be any html/JSX component with toggleable state. Event would be the `onChange` event. Many component libraries have prebuilt switch/toggles that you can customize. Material-UI, AntD, etc... Google is your friend.

Comment: Looks like [toggle switch](https://www.sitepoint.com/react-toggle-switch-reusable-component/)

Comment: There's [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52713990/996081) here which implements a similar control. Many component libraries such as Bootstrap also implement a similar switch control, e.g. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/#switches

Answer (score -1):

They are a Toggle Buttons you can find it from React Bootstrap or React Material Design

https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/buttons/#toggle-button-props

[https://www.syncfusion.com/react-ui-components/react-toggle-switch-button#:~:text=The%20React%20Toggle%20Switch%20Button,label%20positions%2C%20and%20UI%20customization](https://www.syncfusion.com/react-ui-components/react-toggle-switch-button#:%7E:text=The%20React%20Toggle%20Switch%20Button,label%20positions%2C%20and%20UI%20customization).